# directed graph: why x called tail when directed from x to y?

Tags: graph, directed-graph

> An arc (x, y) is considered to be directed from x to y; y is called the head and x is called the tail of the arc.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph

Why isn't x called head when edge directed from x to y?

Comment: This does not sound like a question which has a definite answer. The relevant thing here is that a directed arc is not symmetrical, so it makes sense to have a different name for the head and tail.  The precise name itself dopes not matter.

Comment: The pointy end of an arrow is often called the head.